# CSS not applying locally after webiste has been deployed to Github pages

Tags: css, reactjs, github

Just did a webpage and after deploying this to Github pages (all fine in there, perfectly working) I´ve realized that the local version is not applying CSS anymore (it still shows the page, but without any styling). It was working perfectly fine before. The only thing I did is to deploy it, and since that moment, the local page has not CSS applied even that is linked in the index.html document.

Am I missing something? Is this supposed to happen?

I did previously this with another website and that didn´t occurr.

Now I´m scared that if I make changes in my local files and push this to github, it will mess everything up, so I'm making changes on the github webpage just in case.

I don´t know if it´s relevant, but is a react app.

This is the structure of my files:
[Files structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBBIz.png)

My HTML looks like this:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Drum machine</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root" class="container-fluid"></div>
    <script src="../src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making the code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" />
```

Comment: Hi Maayon, that was the first thing I did and didn´t work. I even tried to import CSS to my  JS file and an error came up. Anyways, the strange thing is that everything used to work fine uppon deployment.